# Is it possible to get AJAX response in Selenium in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have managed to turn on Chrome browser, to go to the specific page, and to click on a submit button on the form. 
My AJAX call is triggered from jQuery file (onclick="saveUserToDb" - in HTML)

I didn't find how to catch resposne from my AJAX request?
Only I can find is ImplicitWait or Explicit Wait..
I've implement that, but I want to be sure that my AJAX gone successfully (statusCode=200)

Here is the example code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        const string prefix = "details";
        // Arrange
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/MyApp.View/");

        //enters to the Manager section
        driver.FindElementById("mngId").Click();

        //expand the menu - codelists
        driver.FindElementById("codelists").Click();

        //entering to the EnterMobile page
        driver.FindElementById("enterMobilePrefix").Click();

        //click on Add for new MobilePrefix
        driver.FindElementById("addMobilePrefix").Click();

        //populate data for MobilePrefix
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        IWebElement codeElement = driver.FindElementById(prefix + "_Code");
        IWebElement coreCodeElement = driver.FindElementById(prefix + "_CoreCode");
        IWebElement valueElement = driver.FindElementById(prefix + "_Value");

        codeElement.SendKeys("10254");
        coreCodeElement.SendKeys("8794");
        valueElement.SendKeys("test55");

        //Calling the AJAX
        driver.FindElementByClassName("btn-info").Click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10));
        wait.Until(driverAjax =>
        {
            bool isAjaxFinished = (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driverAjax).
                ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0");

            return isAjaxFinished;
        });
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        driver.Quit();


        // Assert
        //StringAssert.EndsWith(session.ToString(), "html");
    }
```

Comment: why don't you make a little bit of a trick. 

Set the Ajax response in a hidden element and have it with an ID "AjaxResponse”. The element should be empty while you haven’t sent the request, contain the word FAILED if request failed (you can add a failed message as well) or filled with the Ajax response.

In your C# code after click the button that will send the request. Wait for 500ms then check it. If it was empty wait another 500ms until the total wait time exceed a specified limit. Which by that time you will have the FAILED word in it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/09_selenium_ide.jsp#the-waitfor-commands-in-ajax-applications) I found

This is done using waitFor commands, as waitForElementPresent or waitForVisible, which wait dynamically, checking for the desired condition every second and continuing to the next command in the script as soon as the condition is met.

Another work around that may solve your issue

Set the Ajax response in a hidden element and have it with an ID ex:"AjaxResponse”. The element should be empty while you haven’t sent the request, contain the word FAILED if request failed (you can add a failed message as well) or filled with the Ajax response. In your C# code after click the button that will send the request. Wait for 500ms then check it. If it was empty wait another 500ms until the total wait time exceed a specified limit. Which by that time you will have the FAILED word in the element.

Comment: so basically, I can't catch the ajax response? (like when I put debugger in javascript) I cannot add hidden field, simply because I have hundreds and thousands of AJAX calls in my whole web app :)

Comment: I'm not really sure if there is a way to do it in that exact way. But I usually use the trick I wrote earlier during the testing phase.

Answer (score 0):

My soultion would be to implement Your WaitHelper class:

```
public static class WaitHelper
{
    public static bool WaitFor(int timeoutInMiliseconds, int sleepInMiliseconds, Func<bool> waitForSuccessfullResult)
    {
        return WaitFor(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutInMiliseconds),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(sleepInMiliseconds),
            waitForSuccessfullResult);
    }

    public static bool WaitFor(TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan sleepInverval, Func<bool> waitForSuccessfullResult)
    {
        while (timeout.TotalMilliseconds > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (waitForSuccessfullResult())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured. Details: \n" + e.ToString());
            }

            timeout -= sleepInverval;
            Thread.Sleep(sleepInverval);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Then You could wait for some AjaxRequests like:

```
    public static void WaitForAjaxRequest(this IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        WaitHelper.WaitFor(
            Config.ShortTime,
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            () =>
            {
                return !webDriver.IsAjaxRequestInProgress();
            });
    }

    public static bool IsAjaxRequestInProgress(this IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        return webDriver.ExecuteJs<bool>("return window.jQuery ? window.jQuery.active != 0 : false");
    }
```

Or wait for document ready:

```
    public static void WaitForDocumentReady(this IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        WaitHelper.WaitFor(
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200),
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string readyState = webDriver.ExecuteJs<string>("if (document.readyState) return document.readyState;");
                    var ajaxInProgress = webDriver.IsAjaxRequestInProgress();

                    return readyState.ToLower() == "complete" && !ajaxInProgress;
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    // Window is no longer available
                    return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to get browser");
                }
                catch (WebDriverException e)
                {
                    // Browser is no longer available
                    return e.Message.ToLower().Contains("unable to connect");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
```

JavaScript Executor:

```
    public static T ExecuteJs<T>(this IWebDriver webDriver, string script)
    {
        var javaScriptExecutor = webDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

        if (javaScriptExecutor == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(script);
    }
```